# Stability of singularity in singular holomorphic foliation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, foliations, complex-dynamics

For  an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$  containing $0$ and  a  holomorphic  map $f:U\to \mathbb{C}^{2}$  which has a unique zero at the origin we  associate a natural singular holomorphic foliation  by complex curves, the foliation arising from $\dot z=f(z)$. In this case origin is  called a singularity.

> What is an example of such singular foliation for which the foliation is stable at $0$?

That is,  for every open set $W$ containing origin, there is an open set $V\subset W$ which saturation under foliation is contained in $W$? Is there an indirect relation between this question and  some methods  in "Minimal set problem" about singular holomorphic foliations of $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$?

Note that a  minimal set for  a  singular foliation of  $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ is a  compact subset which is invariant(saturated) under foliation and does not contain any singular point. For "minimal set" see [here](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~zakeri/papers/SHFC_zak.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an example is impossible. We can always assume $W$ is a polydisc, and part of its boundary $\partial W$ is included in the $3$-space $T=\{(x,y) : |y|=r\}$. Take $p\in T\cap\bar W$. If the foliation were stable then the image of $t\mapsto z(t))$,  for small $t$ and with $z(0)=p$, would be included in the adherence of a single connected component of $\mathbb C^2\setminus T$. This contradicts the maximum/minimum modulus  principle for the $y$-component of $z(t)$ except if $z=cst$, but in that case the trajectory escapes from $W$ through another component of the boundary. Therefore every leaf of the foliation passing through $\partial W$ escapes from $W$.

You can adapt this construction to the saturation $S$ of $V$ in $W$, to prove the foliation always reaches $\partial W$. If it were not the case,  consider the smallest closed polydisc $\bar W_S\subsetneq \bar W$ containing $S$. There is a point $p\in\partial S \cap \partial W_S$, to which the above argument applies: either the trajectory passing through $p$ escapes from $W_S$ (contradiction) or it is included in $\partial W_S$ and therefore leaves the polydisc through another component of $\partial W_S$ (contradiction again).

Comment: In fact *every* non-singular trajectory escapes from $W$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think  I can not understand some thing in the last part of  your argument or some thing is missing in your answer. An equivalent definition of stability   is  as follows :for every open set $W$ there is  an open set $V\subset W$ such that $V$ is  saturated. But why we can choose $V$ in the form of  a poly disc? In fact the last part of your statement (which does not depend on real or complex case, I think) is not valid in real case (the center). Moreover By 3-torus do you mean solid two torus?(The boundary is the union of two solid torus)

Comment: Moreover what is the contradiction if in every small neighborhood we have  a leaf with constant y-coordinate? Note that we do not assume that the singularity is  non degenerate.May be it has vanishing linear term.

Comment: Or vanishing k-Jet for k large.

Comment: @AliTaghavi:I never claimed you could take $V$ as a polydisc, I'm sorry if I was unclear. I modified the post in a way which is clearer I hope. Also, there is no problem in having trajectories with constant $y$-coordinate, they just escape from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your  interesting argument. Now I understand your answer. Now I realize that your transversality argument on the boundary  can be applied to usual disc rather than poly discs by the following:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250638/holomorphic-curve-with-unit-norm

Comment: Yes, you're right, the boundary shape of $W$ should not matter much.

Comment: Thanks again for your very interesting answer. your topological consideration is a motivation  (very indirectly) to ask the following topological questions:

Comment: Is there a topological copy $M$ of solid torus in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $\mathbb{R}^{4}-M$ is disconnected?(Motivated by jordan decomposition theorem in arbitrary dimension)

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I'm sorry I have no idea, although it doesn't seem possible at first glance.